# How to order a set< pair< pair<int, int>, double > > for the second value "double"?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, set, compare

I am super new in C++ and I am really struggling with this: I want to organize my second component of the set:

```
set< pair <pair<int, int>, double > > map
int N_t = 10, N_r = 10;
for (unsigned int i_t = 0; i_t < N_t; i_t++ )
 {
 for(unsigned int i_r = 0; i_r < N_r; i_r++ )
  {
   Double_t dR = i_t*i_r ;
   map.insert( make_pair(make_pair(i_r, i_t) ,dR));
   }
 }
```

And I want to organice the second component. I have try this and I dont know how to to it:

```
sort(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const pair<pair<int,int> &x, double>,const pair<pair<int,int>, double> &y)
{
  return x.second < y.second;
 });
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot sort associative containers(set, map, and the unordered counterparts).

Comment: see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set your set can have a custom comparator. With this you can custumize the "order" inside your set and also what is considered "unique"

Comment: And, rather than this recursive use of `std::pair`, why don't you just use a `tuple` or better still a simple `struct` to aggregate the elements?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to sort according to the `.second` element of the pair, then why not placing the `double` in front of the `pair<int,int>`? Sorting orders pairs by their first element then their second element, thus instead of

```
set< pair <pair<int, int>, double > > map
```

You could use

```
set< pair <double, pair<int, int> > > map
```

Also I suggest not using keywords as variable names (`map` is an in-built data structure in C++)

Comment: Thanks Benson!  I just realize that I have to construct a  struct that compares

 struct Cmp
      {
 bool operator ()(const pair< pair<int, int>, double > &a, const pair< pair<int, int>, double >  &b)
 {
   return a.second < b.second;
 }
      };

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Benson!  I just realize that I have to construct a  struct that compares

```
s struct Cmp
  {
   bool operator ()(const pair< pair<int, int>, double > &a, const pair< pair<int, int>, double >  &b)
   {
    return a.second < b.second;
   }
  };
  set< pair< pair<int, int>, double > , Cmp> map;
```

Thanks for the advise!